Extra factor in Fourier transform of $\bar{\gamma}_{\mu \nu}$
In the weak gravity limit (and with proper gauge transformations), the linearized Einstein equation is given by:
$$
\partial^c \partial_c \bar\gamma_{ab} = -16 \pi T_{ab}\tag{4.4.12}
$$
where $$g_{ab} = \eta_{ab} + \gamma_{ab}\tag{4.4.1}$$ and $$\bar{\gamma}_{ab} := \gamma_{ab} - \frac{1}{2}\eta_{ab}\gamma.\tag{4.4.6}$$ Moreover, raised/lowered indices are with respect to the flat metric $\eta_{ab}$ rather than $g_{ab}$. In a coordinate system, this means that each component $\bar{\gamma}_{\mu \nu}$ fulfills the inhomogenous wave equation. According to Wald, the solution is therefore given by:
$$
\bar{\gamma}_{\mu \nu}(x) = 4\int_{\Lambda} \frac{T_{\mu \nu}(x')}{|\bar{x} - \bar{x}'|}dS(x')\tag{4.4.42}
$$
where $\Lambda$ is the past light cone, and  $dS = r^2 dr d\Omega$ is its volume element. This makes sense, since only the spacetime points on the past light cone affect the point in question, following from the nature of the wave equation. I am also assuming that $x$ and $x'$ includes the time, whereas $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{x}'$ only includes the space variables. Lastly, I'm guessing that $\Lambda$ itself is also technically a function of $x$ (in above notation), since the past light cone is different for each spacetime point.
The problem arises in the next part, where the Fourier transform with respect to the time variable $t$ (in an assumed global inertial coordinate system of $\eta_{ab}$) is calculated for $\bar{\gamma}_{\mu \nu}$ and $T_{\mu \nu}$ respectively. The convention used in the book states that the Fourier transform for the component $\bar{\gamma}_{\mu \nu}$ is given by:
$$
\hat{\bar{\gamma}}_{\mu \nu}(\omega, \bar{x}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bar{\gamma}_{\mu \nu}(t, \bar{x})e^{i \omega t}dt.\tag{4.4.43}
$$
However, when trying to relate this Fourier transform of $\bar{\gamma}_{\mu \nu}$ to the Fourier transform of $T_{\mu \nu}$, it says:
$$
\hat{\bar{\gamma}}_{\mu \nu}(\omega, \bar{x}) = 4 \int \frac{\hat{T}_{\mu \nu}(\omega, \bar{x}')}{|\bar{x} - \bar{x}'|}\exp{\left(i \omega |\bar{x} - \bar{x}'|\right)}d^3 x\tag{4.4.44}
$$
and clarifies:

where the "extra" factor $\exp{\left(i \omega |\bar{x} - \bar{x}'|\right)}$ arises from the fact that the original integral (4.4.42) [second equation] was over the past light cone.

At this part, I am a bit lost. After several attempts, I am not able to prove this, yet the book makes it sound obvious. What I have tried so far is:

Substituting the expression for $\gamma_{\mu \nu}(t, \bar{x}) \equiv \gamma_{\mu \nu}(x)$ in the equation for $\hat{\bar{\gamma}}_{\mu \nu}(\omega, \bar{x})$, and trying to split the integral over $\Lambda$ into an integral over time and an integral over space (in hope to replace the temporal integral with the Fourier transform for $T_{\mu \nu}$). This did not work since $T_{\mu \nu}$ is a function of $t'$, whereas the expression $e^{i\omega t}$ is a function of $t$. The only thing depending on $t$, I think, is $\Lambda$.
The exact same approach as 1, but instead trying to swap the integral order of $\int_{\Lambda}$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$. This did not work since $\Lambda$ depends on $t$, and integrating with respect to $\Lambda$ in the outer integral does not get rid of $t$ in the end.
Replacing $\bar{\gamma}_{\mu \nu}(x)$ and $T_{\mu \nu}(x')$ in the first equation with their inverse transforms and seeing if the equation still holds. This got me to a point where I have to integrate over both $d^3 x$ and $dt$, which made it difficult to show how it is the same as integrating over $\Lambda$. (Also, there were more issues with this, and the other approaches, I am just giving some critical examples.)
Trying to Fourier transform both sides of the second equation and use Fourier transform rules. Specifically, I tried using the fact that $$F\left[\int_{-\infty}^{t} g(\tau)d\tau\right] = \frac{G(\omega)}{i\omega} + \pi G(0) \delta(\omega),$$ where $G(\omega) = F[g(t)]$, and splitting the integral over $\Lambda$ into a time integral over $[-\infty, t]$ and a spatial integral. However, in doing so, I'm still left having to find the Fourier transform of the remaining integral over the spatial sphere, which I did not find trivial. It feels like the book would tell me if something like this was required.

My hope is that I am missing something very obvious, or that I am misunderstanding something fundamental. In either case, any help at all is appreciated.

I think Wald is a little fast with the details, especially with knowledge of how to handle wave equation solutions, which are covered in electrodynamics texts (see Jackson, Zangwill, or even Wald's new one). The easiest way to show this is to make the integration on the lightcone explicit with a delta function, which I shall do below.
I will try to do this derivation out since I got lost in the weeds when I first learned this. Let us start with finding the retarded solution to the wave equation (one could in principle also do this with advanced time, but since you want to consider the effects from the past light cone, we must use the retarded solution). Consider the wave equation $$\Box \psi(t,\vec x)=-S(t,\vec x),$$ where $S$ is a source term. Letting $R:=|\vec x-\vec x'|$, this can be solved as $$\psi(t,\vec x)=\frac {1}{4\pi}\int \mathrm d^3 x'\int_\mathbb{R}\mathrm d t'\delta(t'-t+R)\frac{S(t',\vec x')}{R}.$$
Applying this to each component of our tensor equation $\Box \bar \gamma_{\mu\nu}=-16\pi T_{\mu\nu}(t,\vec x)$, we obtain
$$\bar\gamma_{\mu\nu}(t,\vec x)=4\int \mathrm d^3x'\int_\mathbb{R}\mathrm d t'\delta(t'-t+R)\frac{T_{\mu\nu}(t',\vec x')}{R}.$$
This is mathematically equivalent to Wald's expression, where the delta function can be understood as restricting the integration domain to the past light cone since the delta function picks out the retarded--time contributions to the integral. We can then Fourier transform the metric to energy space, giving
$$\hat{\bar\gamma}_{\mu\nu}(\omega,\vec x)=\frac{4}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}\mathrm dt \int \mathrm d^3x'\int_\mathbb{R}\mathrm d t'\delta(t'-t+R)\frac{T_{\mu\nu}(t',\vec x')}{R}e^{i\omega t}.$$
Then, performing the $t$ integral and moving terms around to define the Fourier transform of the stress-energy tensor in energy-space using the $t'$ integral yields
$$\hat{\bar\gamma}_{\mu\nu}(\omega,\vec x)=\frac{4}{\sqrt {2\pi}} \int \mathrm d^3x'\int_\mathbb{R}\mathrm d t'\frac{T_{\mu\nu}(t',\vec x')}{R}e^{i\omega (t'+R)}\\=4 \int \mathrm d^3x'\frac {e^{i\omega R}} R\underbrace{\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}\mathrm d t'T_{\mu\nu}(t',\vec x')e^{i\omega t'}\right\}}_{\equiv\hat T_{\mu\nu}(\omega,\vec x') }=4 \int \mathrm d^3x'\frac {\hat T_{\mu\nu}(\omega,\vec x')e^{i\omega R}} R\\=4 \int \mathrm d^3x'\frac {\hat T_{\mu\nu}(\omega,\vec x')e^{i\omega |\vec x-\vec x'|}} {|\vec x-\vec x'|}.$$
This is exactly what needed to be shown. I think you just needed to use the more mathematically transparent form of the wave equation solution.
